# PayPal's Button Manager API with javascript

Tags: javascript, paypal

What i'd like to achieve is to dynamically create **hosted** PayPal buttons through the Button Manager API offered by PayPal, preferrably the NVP API. I would like to do so using client side Javascript.

Surprisingly, after extensive searching online I've failed to find a sample of code that achieves that goal.
Reading into the PayPal documentation led me to believe that I can use the API with xmlhttprequests. However, I fail to get a reply from PayPal. I've created a string with some arbitrary parameters which should be correct, and come as far as:

```
var xmlhttp;

function generateButton()
{
    console.log("Function begun") ;

    var strUrl= "https://api.paypal.com/nvp";
    var strParameters="?METHOD=BMCreateButton&VERSION=204.0&BUTTONCODE=HOSTED&BUTTONTYPE=BUYNOW&BUTTONSUBTYPE=PRODUCTS&L_BUTTONVAR0=amount=15.00&L_BUTTONVAR1=item_name=test_item2USER=***&PWD=***&SIGNATURE=***";
    var urlRequest= strUrl+encodeURI(strParameters);

    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {
        // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else if (window.ActiveXObject)
    {
        // code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    else
    {
        alert("Your browser does not support XMLHTTP!");
    }
    xmlhttp.open("POST",urlRequest,true);
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange= function(){
        alert(xmlhttp.statusText) ;
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4)
        {
            alert(xmlhttp.responseText) ;
        }
    };
    xmlhttp.send();

}
```

My paypal credentials are listed as *** for privacy purposes, and in my code they are proper. Am I going about this the right way? Are my parameters incorrect, or is the issue with my xmlhttprequest? Bear in mind that I am new to web programming, and detailed explanations would be appreciated.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

After some further reading, it seems calling the Button Manager API through client side javascript is not a correct approach as it requires a cross domain request (which browsers do not allow for security reasons).
It is possible to bypass this restriction with the CORS mechanism, but as far as I can tell PayPal does not support it. Other solutions exist but are 'dirty'.
I've concluded that it is better to make the request through a server. Requests can be made to your own server, which would invoke the button manager API and forward the reply (your new button's HTML code) back to the client.
Here is a NodeJS program code to create a new hosted button, which you can implement in your server:

```
    var querystring = require('querystring'); // to URL encode for the NVP 
    var https = require('https'); // to use the NVP API, request must be https

 // Prototype for a create button request fields, you can get your input from database, client side user or just hard code it
    function CreateButtonRequest(user, pwd, signature, buttonPrice, buttonName){ 
            this.USER =user,
            this.PWD  = pwd,
            this.SIGNATURE = signature,
            this.METHOD = "BMCreateButton",
            this.VERSION = "204.0",
            this.BUTTONCODE = "HOSTED",
            this. BUTTONTYPE = "BUYNOW",
            this.BUTTONSUBTYPE = "PRODUCTS",
            this.L_BUTTONVAR0  = "amount="+buttonPrice,
            this.L_BUTTONVAR1 = "item_name="+buttonName
    }
    // A sample request
    // Replace **** with your API certificate specifics, find them in your paypal account
    sampleRequestData = {   
        USER : "****",
        PWD : "****",
        SIGNATURE : "****",
        METHOD : "BMCreateButton",
        VERSION : "204.0",
        BUTTONCODE : "HOSTED",
        BUTTONTYPE : "BUYNOW",
        BUTTONSUBTYPE : "PRODUCTS",
        L_BUTTONVAR0 : "amount=10.00",
        L_BUTTONVAR1 : "item_name=test item2"

    };

    sampleRequestData = querystring.stringify(postData);
    //init your options object after you call querystring.stringify because you  need
    // the return string for the 'content length' header
    console.log(sampleRequestData) ;
    var options = {
        host: 'api-3t.paypal.com',
        port: 443,
        method: 'POST',
        path: '/nvp',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            'Content-Length': postBody.length
        }
    };



    var postreq = https.request(options, function (res) {
        res.setEncoding('utf8');
        res.on('data', function (chunk) {
            console.log('Response: ' + chunk);
        });
    });
    postreq.write(sampleRequestData);
    postreq.end();
    console.log("Message sent...") ;
```